# Quality questionnaire php mysql graphipcs

Tags: php, mysql, graphics, mean

i'm making a questionnaire about a service quality, its contains the options (poor, regular, good, very good). It's contains 6 questions (radio button) and a suggestion box (textbox).
In the table of the database i created 6 rows for questions, 1 for suggestion and 1 for date (a friend of mine tole me to use this but i didn't get why).

q1) I'm going to atribute a value form 1 to 4 to the radio buttons options, and i'd like to sum every answer for each question, and then divide by the numbers of user that answered that question and give the mean. how am i supposed to to that? I'd also like generate reports of the month, of the year.

q2) not only about the questionnaire but for registration too. I need all the fields to be completed, no blank options, if he don't complete all of fields it'll not be submitted and there will be a warning message to the user.

q3) about the field type, i'd like it to be the same class that is in the database, i'm having a "problem". Ex: Name(varchar) : 1234(int), in the field 'name' of the table of the database 1234 will be shown as name, and i don't want this, i want only the type that i declared in the construction of the table.

q4) i'd also like to know if it's possible to create pizza graphics, about the percentage of each question, is this possible?

q5) I'm using phpmyadmin and some of my id's are auto_increment, but 'cause of my tests they at a high number, i'd like to restart to 0 the ids number, is this possible?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: wow 5 questions and not a single break line

Comment: Did you mean: *questionnaire*?

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like what you more need is a complete surveying package.  This has been done before and there are many great paid and free options.

If you are attached to a php/mysql answer, a quick search finds this as a nice open source option.
http://www.limesurvey.org/